# How can my clients update their card information on Stripe?

Tags: stripe-payments

I currently use Stripe to sell my product, namely a recurring subscription.
I sometimes see a recurring payment failed to be completed, but Stripe, unlike PayPal seems to not support out of the box email notifications to let the customer know that his payment has failed.

So, my questions are:

1. How can I email my clients to notify them about their payment having failed? ( tell it as if I am 7 year old please, I am not a programmer )
2. Most importantly, how can my clients update their card information?

Comment: This is a question that should be directed to Stripe support IHMO.

Comment: I know Krtek, they just send me to complex instructional pages that require advanced knowledge of programming languages. I am a small business owner, I unfortunately have no time to become a PHP expert and only after that manage to send a simple email to my clients.  That is why I posted here, to see if someone has knows of a more simple way to get this done.

Comment: Even for PHP developers it's nearly impossible to understand the Stripe docs :)

Answer (score 10):

1. The best way to be notified when a recurring payment fails, and in turn notify your own customer, is to use [webhooks](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks). Specifically, you'd need to catch the [`invoice.payment_failed`](https://stripe.com/docs/api#event_types-invoice.payment_failed) event.

   Here is a recipe that explains how to send emails for failed payments to customers (using PHP): https://stripe.com/docs/recipes/sending-emails-for-failed-payments.
2. To update the payment information of an existing customer, you'd need to first collect the new card's information (using [Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout) or your own form with [Stripe.js](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe.js)), then send a [customer update](https://stripe.com/docs/api#update_customer) request with the new card's token in the [`source`](https://stripe.com/docs/api#update_customer-source) parameter. This will replace the customer's current default card with the new one.

Comment: `Source` api is deprecated right? I have created `payment_method`. How can I set `payment_method` as user's default

Answer (score 10):

You can email a link to the customer to update their credit card:

1. Use “Customer” tab to search for customer
2. Click on customer to open details
3. Click on “subscribed to…” (1st section of page)
4. Invoices:  click on most recent invoice
5. “Details” section: copy “payment page link” and email to customer

Comment: Untrue, this works perfectly fine — I had a customer update their payment details for a subscription just last week using this exact method.

Simply navigate to the most recent Invoice in the Stripe dashboard, then copy the link under Details > Payment page. 

This method is far simpler & faster than any of the other answers and requires no additional implementation.

Comment: Payment page has no way to update the credit card now (May 2022): https://i.imgur.com/vMporGL.png

Answer (score 5):

This is now all done by Stripe's Customer Portal.  Very feature-rich.

https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/integrating-customer-portal

Comment: But is there a way to link to the portal to send it out in an email before fully integrating it into the app?

Answer (score 1):

After talking with Stripe support this worked for me to allow the customer to edit his credit card informations (May 2022):

- stripe dashboard
- customers
- select your customer in the list
- remove all existing payment methods of the customer
- create a new invoice ("Create" button at the top of the invoice list)
- add a new item with an amount of 0.5$ (minimum amount apparently) By indicating an amount of 0$ the window to indicate the card data is not displayed.
- check the "email invoice to customer with link to payment page" box
- review invoice (top right button)
- click on the send button

Personally, I had to do this twice for the customer to see the form to enter the new credit card data but it finally worked...

I hope this will help some of you who tried the previous solutions without success.

Answer (score 1):

You can enable a shareable link to your customer portal that customers can log in to by email address to do things like manage their card information.

Here's where you configure it and enable the shareable link (at the bottom of this page)

https://dashboard.stripe.com/settings/billing/portal

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this now as of 3/13/23 is to go into your account

Click on Billing
Then look to the left for Invoices
Then in the list find the failed payment
Click it

When here (see screenshot)
https://www.loom.com/i/7029ac5972aa4ee4b1671c79fa3913d0

Then click Show More

Then click Invoice payment

Take that URL and send it to the client however you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you upgrade to the Stripe Scale plan, Stripe sends customers emails at appropriate times so that they can renew their billing information.